# How can i login in a webservice using my android app?

Tags: android, web-services

I am making an app that opens with a login page.I am trying to login in a webservice. We need to enter the user id and password. After entering the correct values the app should move to a next activity where json data from the server will be displayed.
I am using Retrofit for this but i am not able to connect my app with the login page. How do i do that?

Comment: provide your Retrofit code

Comment: i haven't started coding yet as i am very confused on how to use Retrofit. i have seen a lot of codes and tutorials regarding this and all it did was confuse me more.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is advance rest api consumer , please use some easy way to connect to the network . Use volley , or use HTTP Client directly to connect and then parse the response coming from the web service using JsonParser class in Android.

Comment: I was told that retrofit is the easiest way to do that. Anyways, what do u suggest i should use?